Rating CSS on hover
I have a rating system. By default all stars are grey and empty.
When a user hovers or clicks a star I want that star and the preceding stars (to the left of it) to become solid. I can get the stars to become solid, but it works inverted, i.e. when I hover over a star, the stars to the right of it become solid.
JavaScript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a');

    stars.forEach(star => {
        star.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            stars.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('active')); // Clear active class from all stars
            star.classList.add('active'); // Add active class to the clicked star
            let previousSibling = star.previousElementSibling;
            while (previousSibling) {
                previousSibling.classList.add('active'); // Add active class to all previous stars
                previousSibling = previousSibling.previousElementSibling;
            }

            const ratingValue = star.getAttribute('class').split('-')[1];
            const ratingSelect = document.getElementById('rating');
            if (ratingSelect) {
                ratingSelect.value = ratingValue;
            }
        });
    });
});

CSS
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a {
    background: none; /* Removes background */
    padding: 0; /* Removes padding */
    font-size: 0; /* Hides the text */
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    font-weight: 300; /* Light font */
    position: relative; /* Ensure stacking context for z-index */
    z-index: 1; /* Make sure these are above the pseudo-elements */ 
}

/* Setting the FontAwesome star */
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a:before {
    content: '\f005'; /* FontAwesome star */
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ccc; /* Default gray color */
}

/* Reset all stars to default color when hovering on the container */
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars:hover a:before {
    color: #ccc;
}

/* Fill stars in gold when they or their siblings are hovered over */
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a:hover:before,
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a:hover ~ a:before {
    color: #FFD700; /* Gold color */
    font-weight: 900; /* Solid weight for filled stars */
}

/* Active state for clicked star and its preceding stars */
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a.active:before,
.comment-respond .comment-form-rating .stars a.active ~ a:before {
    color: #FFD700; /* Gold color */
    font-weight: 900; /* Solid weight for filled stars */
}


I couldn't find the rating stars on the "Beoordelingen" tab. Are they opened only for logged in users?

You're right, fixed now

could not find it either

Your code seems ok for me. Maybe check how stars are displayed, maybe flex-direction is reverse

Just tested again and I see it, added update 1 with an image of what you should see.

a:hover ~ a:before you're filling stars to the right of active.
